# create listview with alphabetic separators android - how?

Tags: android, android-listview, list-separator

I have the following code. I need to create list separators  before A elements, B and so on. I need to have someting like this: A Ana Al...B Bob Bill...C Cane Cod...Z Zane. How to impove my code? need some help. I am new to android and I really don't know how to solve this.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="100dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />  


</RelativeLayout>
```

**item1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="100dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />  

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textSeparator"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center" 
android:text="text" 
android:visibility="visible" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
android:background="#FFFF0000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**.java**

```
package scroll.packet;


    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Set;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SectionIndexer;

    public class FastScrollActivity extends Activity {
            ListView myListView;
            ArrayList<String> elements;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);

                    // elements
                    String s = "QWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM";
                    Random r = new Random();
                    elements = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {

                            elements.add(s.substring(r.nextInt(s.length())));

                    }
                    Collections.sort(elements); // Must be sorted!

                    // listview
                    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
                    myListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);


                    //myListView.
                    MyIndexerAdapter<String> adapter = new MyIndexerAdapter<String>(
                                    getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                    elements);
                    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

          //          if (myListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > adapter.getItemId( adapter.getCount()) || myListView.getLastVisiblePosition() <= adapter.getCount()) {
           //               myListView.smoothScrollToPosition( adapter.getCount());}

            }
```

UPDATE CODE

```
    class MyIndexerAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> implements SectionIndexer {

    ArrayList<String> myElements;
    HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;
    TreeSet mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet();
    String[] sections;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyIndexerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                    List<T> objects) {


            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            mInflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            myElements = (ArrayList<String>) objects;
            // here is the tricky stuff
            alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // in this hashmap we will store here the positions for
            // the sections

            int size = elements.size();
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    String element = elements.get(i);
                    alphaIndexer.put(element.substring(0, 1), i);
            //We store the first letter of the word, and its index.
            //The Hashmap will replace the value for identical keys are putted in
            }

            // now we have an hashmap containing for each first-letter
            // sections(key), the index(value) in where this sections begins

            // we have now to build the sections(letters to be displayed)
            // array .it must contains the keys, and must (I do so...) be
            // ordered alphabetically

            Set<String> keys = alphaIndexer.keySet(); // set of letters ...sets
            // cannot be sorted...

            Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
            ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(); // list can be
            // sorted

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String key = it.next();
                    keyList.add(key);
            }

            Collections.sort(keyList);

            sections = new String[keyList.size()]; // simple conversion to an
            // array of object
            keyList.toArray(sections);

            // ooOO00K !

    }

 public int getItemViewType(int position)
 {
     return  mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
 }

 public int getViewTypeCount()
 {
     return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
 }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
            // Log.v("getPositionForSection", ""+section);
            String letter = sections[section];

            return alphaIndexer.get(letter);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {

            // you will notice it will be never called (right?)
            Log.v("getSectionForPosition", "called");
            getSections();
            return 0;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {

            return sections; // to string will be called each object, to display
            // the letter
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent,View v, int position, long id)
    {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "you have selected" + elements.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    //break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(elements.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}

public void quickScroll(View v) {
    String alphabet = (String)v.getTag();
    int index = 0;
    //find the index of the separator row view
    list.setSelectionFromTop(index, 0);
}


public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
}
```

Comment: Below is the excellent tutorial about listview android listview divider.I hope this will help you.you can add separator without declaring it in xml file. http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Comment: i've seen the tutorial, but i don't know how to adapt it to my code:(. Can you please please help? I need the list to be in alphabetic order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your adapter you have to override [getViewTypeCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and [getViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)

the latter will get the type of View that will be created by getView (In your case the view that contains only the starting letter and the view that contains the name), the former will returns the number of types of Views that will be created by `getView()`

Comment: where? what is the "yourdrawable? can you please exend? I need to have A...,B, C,..AND SO on as saparators. I mean i need something identical with the contact list in android

Comment: for separator what you mean? Something that separate every element of your listview from the next?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. I will delete my answer

Comment: I've updated my code. I need alphabetic separators before A B C..and so on. Do you know how to solve this/

Comment: ok you do not need a separator for this purpose. You need to override getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount(). The latter will return the number of different view you need to inflate. I think 2 in your case because you need a view to put the initial letter, and then a list of name with start with the that letter, and the latter the view for the name. getItemViewType() will return the view the kind of view.

Comment: update your code and point out the line it is causing the exception

Comment: i've updated my code. . I don't have any errors but I is not working correclty. need some help:) I need separators before words that starts with A , words that starts with B and..so on till on Z

Comment: convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null); you are inflating the same view. Just for the sake of clean code you Create two different xml files one for the separator and one for the normale view and then inflate in the swicth.

Comment: OK. I've updated my code. still not working. All the elements A,B,C,D are serapators. Where Am I wrong. I need just 1 separator

Comment: I also need to declare the addSeparatorItem void method. how to define in it the position for each element A,,B,..C

Comment: yep. How to check in getItemViewType if positon == index? How to define and declare index based on my code? can you please light me up? My methhod getItemViewType is not correct set . How to set it? I need the first position from letter A,B...